# Better way to extend angular material components

Tags: angular, material-design

I need some directions on this.
I'm creating some components, using angular material design framework. Components like, "app-email", "app-phone", "app-bla"...

In the case of app-phone my first attempt was:

```html
<mat-form-field class="float-auto">
   <input matInput [placeholder]="placeholder"
     class="form-control"
     mask="(00) 0000-0000"
     [ngModel]="value">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

This works greate, and display a phone icon within the input.

But I needed to hack the "placeholder" attribute, so I can use it in my component:

```html
<app-phone placeholder="Phone" formControlName="phone"></app-phone>
```

What I have to do to avoid this without loose the wrap "mat-form-field" ?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: The problem is that any other attribute from the "input" element I will need to recreate in my component.

Answer (score 0):

You can take input of placeholder in your  component and then bind it to the html placeholder

```html
<!-- <app-phone placeholder="Phone" formControlName="phone"></app-phone> -->

<app-phone  phoneInputData="dataObject" formControlName="phone"></app-phone>
```

so now in `app-phone` componnent.ts you can take an `@Input() placeholder:string` and then the same would be binded in app-phone.component.html like this

```js
@Input phoneInputData:Object;
```

```html
<!--  using [placeholder]="{{placeholder}}" binding  -->
<!-- <mat-form-field class="float-auto">
   <input matInput [placeholder]="{{placeholder}}"
     class="form-control"
     mask="(00) 0000-0000"
     [ngModel]="value">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
-->

<mat-form-field class="float-auto">
   <input matInput [placeholder]="{{phoneInputData.placeholder}}"
     class="form-control"
     mask="(00) 0000-0000"
     [ngModel]="value">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I did that in my solution. I was trying to avoid this approach because every attribute and event from input I will need to recreate in my component.

Comment: you can object with the same key value pairs so that you can get it while binding into the component . updated the answer